# Visualizing matrix values in real time

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a 5x5 matrix. 
The elements of the matrix change (are refreshed) every second.

I would like to be able to display the matrix (not as a colormap but with the actual values in a grid) in realtime and watch the values in it change as time progresses.

How would I go about doing so in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `clc` and `disp` is the easiest approach (as answered by Tim), here's a "prettier" approach you might fancy, depending on your needs. This is not going to be as quick, but you might find some benefits, such as not having to clear the command window or being able to colour-code and save the figs.

Using `dispMatrixInFig` (code at the bottom of this answer) you can view the matrix in a figure window (or unique figure windows) at each stage.

Example test code:

```
fig = figure;
% Loop 10 times, pausing for 1sec each loop, display matrix
for i=1:10
    A = rand(5, 5);
    dispMatrixInFig(A,fig)
    pause(1)
end
```

Output for one iteration:

[image: matrix in fig]

Commented function code:

```
function dispMatrixInFig(A, fig, strstyle, figname)
%% Given a figure "fig" and a matrix "A", the matrix is displayed in the 
% figure. If no figure is supplied then a new one is created.
%
% strstyle is optional to specify the string display of each value, for 
% details see SPRINTF. Default is 4d.p. Can set to default by passing '' or
% no argument.
%
% figname will appear in the title bar of the figure.

    if nargin < 2
        fig = figure;
    else
        clf(fig);
    end
    if nargin < 3 || strcmp(strstyle, '')
        strstyle = '%3.4f';
    end
    if nargin < 4
        figname = '';
    end

    % Get size of matrix
    [m,n] = size(A);

    % Turn axes off, set origin to top left
    axis off;
    axis ij;
    set(fig,'DefaultTextFontName','courier', ...
            'DefaultTextHorizontalAlignment','left', ...
            'DefaultTextVerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
            'DefaultTextClipping','on');
    fig.Name = figname;    
    axis([1, m-1, 1, n]);

    drawnow
    tmp = text(.5,.5,'t');
    % height and width of character
    ext = get(tmp, 'Extent');
    dy = ext(4);
    wch = ext(3);
    dwc = 2*wch; 
    dx = 8*wch + dwc; 

    % set matrix values to fig positions
    x = 1;
    for i = 1:n
        y = 0.5 + dy/2;
        for j = 1:m
            y = y + 1;
            text(x,y,sprintf(strstyle,A(j,i)));
        end
        x = x + dx;
    end

    % Tidy up display
    axis([1-dwc/2 1+n*dx-dwc/2 1 m+1]);
    set(gca, 'YTick', [], 'XTickLabel',[],'Visible','on');
    set(gca,'XTick',(1-dwc/2):dx:x);
    set(gca,'XGrid','on','GridLineStyle','-');

end
```

Comment: Nice one ... another approach could be `openvar('A')` which displays the array editor that gets automatically updated upon any changes to `A` ... a look to [linkdata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkdata.html) might be interesting too if willing to update some plot instead of visualizing values

Comment: I tried to manipulate the array editor by command with `v = desktop.getGroupContainer('Variables');` or `v = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLArrayEditorServices` but apart from making array edition read-only or not that's too tricky to undock edition of variable in it's own figure by command

Comment: @CitizenInsane, I did run a couple of quick tests at just opening the variable, but it doesn't seem to reliably update each iteration.

Comment: A `drawnow`is required to update plots/variables during loop

Comment: @CitizenInsane If I run `openvar('A'); for i=1:10 \\ A = rand(5, 5); drawnow; pause(1); \\ end` (where backslashes mean new line) then no update is seen in the variable until after 10 seconds

Comment: You're right seems to only automatically update when stopped in debug mode or a command prompt only // drawnow does not help in forcing synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought you could achieve this with `disp`:

```
for i=1:10
    A = rand(5, 5);
    disp(A);
end
```

If you mean that you don't want repeated outputs on top of each other in the console, you could include a `clc` to clear the console before each `disp` call:

```
for i=1:10
    A = rand(5, 5);
    clc;
    disp(A);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your matrix on a figure it is quite easy. Just make a dump matrix and display it. Then use text function to display your matrix on the figure. For example

```
randMatrix=rand(5); 
figure,imagesc(ones(20));axis image;
hold on;text(2,10,num2str(randMatrix))
```

[image]

If you want to do it in a for loop and see the numbers change, try this:

```
for i=1:100;
  randMatrix=rand(5); 
  figure(1),clf
  imagesc(ones(20));axis image;
  hold on;text(2,10,num2str(randMatrix));
  drawnow;
end
```

Comment: Pretty short, you'll want to add some formatting to the strings  (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#btf97wr) within `num2str` so that each column is the same width, and so aligns well.